# NSPredicate, whitespaces in CoreData. How to trim in predicate?

Tags: objective-c, ios, sqlite, core-data, nspredicate

I have a CoreData/SQLite application in which I have "Parent Categories" and "Categories". I do not have control over the data, some of the "Parent Categories" values have trailing white spaces.

I could use `CONTAINS` (or I should say it works with `CONTAINS` but this is something I can not use). For example I have 2 entries, MEN and MENS. If I use `CONTAINS` I will return both records, you can see how this would be an issue.

I can easily trim on my side, but the predicate will compare that with the database and will not match. So my question is how can I account for whitespaces in the predicate, if possible at all.

I have a category "MENS" which someone has selected in the application, and it is compared against "MENS   " in the database.

Comment: Better question: why hasn't the data in your store been cleaned? Then you wouldn't have this issue.

Comment: You can use CONTAINS and assume it may return more than 1 record, then loop through the results of the fetch checking for 'isEqualToString`?

Answer (score 1):

I would trim the data prior to doing the lookup. You can do this easily using`stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet`. By doing it beforehand, you'll also avoid any performance hit. That could be expensive if you're doing a character based comparison with`CONTAINS`.

So, let's say your search string is "MEN".

Here's the way to strip out any dodgy characters:

```
NSString *trimmed = [@"MEN  " stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
```

There's also`whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet`which does what it says on the tin.

Alternatively, it's easy to create your own custom character of stuff you want to trim.

For that, have a look at:

[NSCharacterSet Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCharacterSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

and

Apple's [String Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/introStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000035i)